# Can I set a printer as default for a specific page size?

Tags: windows-7, pdf, printing

Simple problem, but I was not able to find a solution on my own...

All day long I am printing either 8.5" x 11" PDF reports or 3" x 4" PDF labels.

**If the PDF page size is 8.5" x 11" I'd like the default printer set to my inkjet printer.**

**If the PDF page size is 3" x 4" I'd like the default printer to be my thermal label printer.**

I am using Acrobat Reader now and can't find any settings that would allow this. I am open to using any PDF reader that has this functionality.

Thanks!!

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: @Raystafarian Windows 7 x64. Any ideas?

Comment: Its not currently possible.  Sorry.

Comment: You want a program/ hack/ seting which can automaticly recognize paper size and then send it to the proper printer?

Answer (score 0):

You could make use of a [virtual printer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_printer) as an intermediary. You may know the concept of a virtual printer already; a lot of people have one installed to convert pages to pdf.

Your PC can install one 'printer' which actually is a frontend configured to look at the paper size and determine the real printer based on that.

Which software to use depends on your exact situation (only your PC or more, freeware or willing to pay something, etc).